# My phone keeps clicking on things that I'm not even clicking on?

Tags: touchscreen, 7.0-nougat, system-freeze, 7.1-nougat

Sometimes my Sony xperia z5 just start freezing, clicking on apps, turning drawer's pages and doing things like that without me doing anything . In my opinion it looks like a problem with the touchscreen and the display because it's like if someone touches it but nobody is actually doing it, I am also pretty sure that there isn't any virus . Do you have any idea about the causes of this?

Ps: My phone got the latest firmware and not a modified rom

Comment: Sometimes, such problem occurs due to overheating of device because of continuous usage.

Comment: It could be it considering my phone has a snapdragon 810 which gets hot really fast...

Comment: I have faced this issue in my Samsung core prime. The device used to heat up real fast. I know the pain :)

Comment: Hardware problem. Your digitizer may be defective. You should consider taking it to a repair shop

Answer (score 0):

My phone had same issue, this touchscreen issue got me my phone replaced which was under valid warranty.

You should take it to the respective mobile service centre.